# R functions to trim data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

below is a sample data frame and I would like to trim and data frame by extracting different columns:

```
> c1<-c(1:10)
> c2<-c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,9)
> c3<-c(11:20)
> df<-data.frame(c1,c2,c3)
> df
   c1 c2 c3
1   1  1 11
2   2  2 12
3   3  3 13
4   4  4 14
5   5  5 15
6   6  4 16
7   7  3 17
8   8  2 18
9   9  1 19
10 10  9 20
```

Say if I wanna skip the entire top and bottom row, which shall be like:

[image]

Is there a function where I can extract the data frame or to eliminate certain rows? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dplyr` package has multiple functions to assist with this

`slice` keeps the rows or requested (or removes those with a "-" in front of them)

```
df |>
  slice(-c(1, n()))
```

or equivalently,

```
slice(df, -c(1, n()))
```

`filter` let's you keep the rows with specified conents

```
df |>
  filter(c1 > 1)
```

Commas act like "and" (so both requirements must be true)

```
df |>
  filter(
    c1 > 1,
    c3 < 20
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can index rows like below

```
> df[2:(nrow(df) - 1), ]
  c1 c2 c3
2  2  2 12
3  3  3 13
4  4  4 14
5  5  5 15
6  6  4 16
7  7  3 17
8  8  2 18
9  9  1 19
```

or with `head` + `tail`

```
> tail(head(df, -1), -1)
  c1 c2 c3
2  2  2 12
3  3  3 13
4  4  4 14
5  5  5 15
6  6  4 16
7  7  3 17
8  8  2 18
9  9  1 19
```